# jQuery remove duplicated div with class name

Tags: jquery

So basically my div generates like this:

```
<div class="test className">content</div>
<div class="test className">content</div>
<div class="test className">content</div>
..
<div class="test className">content</div>
```

and I'm trying to remove duplicated divs and keep last one only! any quick ideas? thanks!

Comment: the duplication status is defined by the text content?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A *quick idea* based on your provided markup.

```
var $div = $('div.test.className:contains(content)');

if ($div.length > 1) {
   $div.not(':last').remove()
}
```

<sub>But I would prevent duplication at first place.</sub>

**edit**: Here is another alternative using `filter` and `slice` method:

```
$('.test.className').filter(function() {
    return this.textContent === 'content';
}).slice(0, -1).remove();
```

In the above snippet by using `-1` as the second argument of the `.slice` method, the last element in the set is ignored.

Answer (score 8):

something like this:

```
​$('.className').not(':last')​.remove();​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

select all divs with `.className`, remove the last one from the selection, remove the collection of divs, and you will just keep the last one.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/j5728/

Comment: This assumes all `p`s are equal. I don't think this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

**ORIGINAL (See edit below)**

As [Jan Dvorak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499214/jan-dvorak) has asked, I'm not sure which properties you believe determine that an element is a duplication of another, however, the following is a not particularly *quick* but more generic solution to your problem:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.removeDuplicates = function() {
    var original = [];

    this.each(function() {
      var el = this, $el, isDuplicate;

      $.each(original, function() {
        $el = $(el);

        // check whichever properties 
        // you believe determine whether 
        // it's a duplicate or not
        if (el.tagName === this.tagName && 
            el.className === this.className && 
            el.id === this.id && 
            el.value === this.value && 
            el.href === this.href && 
            $el.html() === $(this).html()) {
          isDuplicate = true;
          $el.remove();
        }
      });

      if (!isDuplicate) {
        original.push(el);
      }
    });
  };
}(jQuery));
```

You would use it like this:

```
$('.test').removeDuplicates();

// .. or even
$('div').removeDuplicates();

// .. or even
$('.test.className').removeDuplicates();
```

All of the above should work as expected, as [demonstrated here](http://jsbin.com/ukayom/1/edit).

**EDIT**

It's been a few years since I wrote this and I have since learnt of [Node.isEqualNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isEqualNode). It gives a much cleaner way to do this so the updated plugin would look like the following (and would return the original element to chain against):

```
(function($) {
  'use strict';

  $.fn.removeDuplicates = function() {
    var $original = $([]);

    this.each(function(i, el) {
      var $el = $(el),
          isDuplicate;

      $original.each(function(i, orig) {
        if (el.isEqualNode(orig)) {
          isDuplicate = true;
          $el.remove();
        }
      });

      if (!isDuplicate) {
        $original = $original.add($el);
      }
    });

    return $original;
  };

}(jQuery));
```

A working example is [demonstrated here](http://jsbin.com/lovakulope/edit?html,js,output).