# Remove duplicate divs with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="section-header Generator" style="display: table-row;">Generator</div>
<div class="section-header Generator" style="display: table-row;">Generator</div>
<div class="section-header Generator" style="display: table-row;">Generator</div>
<div class="section-header Engine" style="display: table-row;">Engine</div>
<div class="section-header Engine" style="display: table-row;">Engine</div>
<div class="section-header Battery" style="display: table-row;">Battery</div>
```

Using JQuery, I want to remove the duplicates- so the above list would become:

```
<div class="section-header Generator" style="display: table-row;">Generator</div>
<div class="section-header Engine" style="display: table-row;">Engine</div>
<div class="section-header Battery" style="display: table-row;">Battery</div>
```

Any ideas how I'd acheive that? There's an old answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791183/jquery-remove-duplicated-div-with-class-name) but it doesn't appear to relate to my issue

Comment: You have not mentioned in the question that there are hundreds of classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```js
 
 $('.section-header').each(function(i, v){ 
    var className = '.'+$(this).attr('class').split(' ').join('.');
    $(className + ":not(:first)").remove(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="section-header Generator" style="display: table-row;">Generator</div>
<div class="section-header Generator" style="display: table-row;">Generator</div>
<div class="section-header Generator" style="display: table-row;">Generator</div>
<div class="section-header Engine" style="display: table-row;">Engine</div>
<div class="section-header Engine" style="display: table-row;">Engine</div>
<div class="section-header Battery" style="display: table-row;">Battery</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution is here- I realised I was using the wrong search terms:

```
var seen = {};
$('.table-section-header').each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    if (seen[txt])
        $(this).remove();
    else
        seen[txt] = true;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use eq() to target the second element with that class (it is zero based):

```
$('.Type your class here').eq(1).remove();
```

do that for every class

Comment: There are hundreds of classes so this is pretty impractical.